# Opting out of reviewing suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is there any way to opt out of being prompted (via the notification in the top bar) to review Suggested Edits? Sorry, but I simply don't have the time.

If there isn't a way to opt out, why isn't there?

Comment: @Werner I think the OP here is wanting to opt out of seeing the notification in the top bar.

Comment: I specifically asked about opting out of being *prompted* to review. Of course I can ignore them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way that SE has for you to choose not to be notified of suggested edits in the *top/towards right corner* of the top bar. They have that in place so more people participate.

You can however, just choose to ignore it.

Or you can do a custom script where you hide it, so you don't have to see it.

Here's the css that targets it

```
.topbar .topbar-links .icon-flag.icon-tools-flag .unread-count { display: none; }
```