# Allow opting out of review queues notifications

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, notifications

Yes, we should all serve our military duty.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

But for those that aren't interested, we shouldn't need to rely on hacks.

[Opting out of reviewing suggested edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224315/opting-out-of-reviewing-suggested-edit)

Yes, when we reach 18 we get the right to vote.

But not registering to vote is also a right.

Sure, "just ignore the notifications."

Well, allowing one to opt-out of that category of notifications should also be made possible.

Comment: What “hacks” are you referring to?

Comment: I’m a little bit not understanding the question…

Comment: @ElementsInSpace I think the "hack" meant, is the one in the answer to the linked question. A custom script to hide the notifications.

Comment: Not voting is a right - not registering to vote isn't. But to be more constructive: what exactly bothers you about it? A grey/red dot in the upper right corner of your screen?

Comment: Yup, for me any red icons are like ringing telephones. I can't train myself to only pick up the telephone to the left, and ignore the one on the right.

Answer (score 8):

> Yes, when we reach 18 we get the right to vote.
>
> But not registering to vote is also a right.

Where I live, there is no voter registration. So, there is also no possibility to not register.

When there is an election for e.g. parliament or the local council, everyone who lives in the relevant area automatically gets sent a voters pass that allows you to vote in the election. You just have the option (and right) to not show up on election day.

As mentioned in the question you linked to, the notification is to get more people to use the review queues, so from that viewpoint it is illogical to provide an option to suppress the notification.

Comment: OK, many people will see the red icon and excitedly go visit the review queue. Just like wow, there's a new restaurant in town and often they have new things on the menu that everybody is excited about. But wait, there are a few sworn vegetarians in town who, well, don't need to be reminded over and over about something they wish to say they  guarantee not to want to be told about over and over, via red notification icons.